# Embed youtube video in iFrame

Tags: angularjs, iframe, youtube, ionic-framework, youtube-api

I am trying to embed videos in my ionic app.

```
<div ng-show="showVideo" align="center">
  <iframe margin="0" padding="0" border="none" width="700" height="400" frameBorder="0"
      ng-src="{{exercise_video_url}}">
 </iframe>  
</div>
```

*exercise_video_url* I get from my database whose value is something like:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/iLOvmdrO*** (last letters *ed for privacy reason)

When the video is finished I see this:
[image]

How can I get rid of these suggestions and just play my video?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `?rel=0` to the end of the embed url and it removes the similar video suggestions.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/iLOvmdrO***?rel=0